# cannot remove UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I create `SearchBarView`, a subclass of `UIView`, and added `UISearchBar` as a subview to it. After calling `removeFromSuperview` on `SearchBarView` (from `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`) the `UISearchBar` does not disappear. I tried to call `removeFromSuperview` on `SearchBarView` from where I created SearchBarView but it did not help. Any ideas why?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SearchBarView : UIView <UISearchBarDelegate> {
    UISearchBar *querySearchBar;
}
@end

#import "SearchBarView.h"
@implementation SearchBarView
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        querySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,frame.size.width,44)];
        querySearchBar.delegate = self;
        [self addSubview:querySearchBar];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchBarDelegate methods
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self removeFromSuperview];    
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{   
    searchBar.text = @""; 
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES]; 
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{  
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES]; 
    return YES;   
}  

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{  
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];  
    return YES;    
}  
@end
```

SearchBarView is created as follows:

```
SearchBarView *searchBarView = [[SearchBarView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 300)];
UIView *rootView = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController].view;
[rootView addSubview:searchBarView];
```

Comment: Can we see the code where you add SearchBarView to the screen and where you attempt to remove it please.

Comment: I added the code that adds SearchBarView. I remove it in searchBarSearchButtonClicked above. It should work like this, right?

Comment: Have you tried [super removeFromSuperview];

Comment: [super removeFromSuperview]; does not work either. I noticed that it is removed when I search second time but it returns null string. That means that it was removed on the first time but was still displayed on the screen. Still cannot find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is

```
[self addSubview:querySearchBar];
```

If you add searchcontroller to subview, then when you do these it does not work.

```
[searchController.searchBar removeFromSuperview()]

self.definesPresentationContext = true

searchController.active = false
```

I suggest your to do

```
presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And try to dismiss searchController

```
[searchController.searchBar removeFromSuperview()]
```

Answer (score -2):

try

```
[searchbar removefromsuperview];
```